# Speeding up an L-System renderer in C#/WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, directx, slimdx, l-systems

[lsys](http://benvan.co.uk/lsys/) is a *blazing fast* [L-System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-system) renderer written in CoffeeScript.

Below is a simple renderer in C# and WPF. It is hardcoded to render [this example](http://benvan.co.uk/lsys/#?i=12&r=L%20:%20%7C-S!L!Y%0AS%20:%20%5BF%5BFF-YS%5DF%29G%5D%2b%0AY%20:--%5BF-%29%3CF-FG%5D-%0AG:%20FGF%5BY%2b%3EF%5D%2bY&p.size=14.11,-1.359672&p.angle=-3963.7485,-0.138235&s.size=8.7,7.4&s.angle=7.7,4&offsets=0,105,90&name=tree%20horse). The result when run looks as follows:

[image]

A mouse-click in the window will adjust the `angleGrowth` variable. The re-calculation of the `GeometryGroup` as well as building the `Canvas` usually take much less than a tenth of a second. However, the actual screen update seems to take much longer.

Any suggestions for how to make this faster or more efficient? It's currently way slower than the CoffeeScript/JavaScript version... :-)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WpfLsysRender
{
    class DrawingVisualElement : FrameworkElement
    {
        public DrawingVisual visual;

        public DrawingVisualElement() { visual = new DrawingVisual(); }

        protected override int VisualChildrenCount { get { return 1; } }

        protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index) { return visual; }
    }

    class State
    {
        public double size;

        public double angle;

        public double x;

        public double y;

        public double dir;

        public State Clone() { return (State) this.MemberwiseClone(); }
    }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        static string Rewrite(Dictionary<char, string> tbl, string str)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (var elt in str)
            {
                if (tbl.ContainsKey(elt))
                    sb.Append(tbl[elt]);
                else
                    sb.Append(elt);
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Width = 800;
            Height = 800;

            var states = new Stack<State>();

            var str = "L";

            {
                var tbl = new Dictionary<char, string>();

                tbl.Add('L', "|-S!L!Y");
                tbl.Add('S', "[F[FF-YS]F)G]+");
                tbl.Add('Y', "--[F-)<F-FG]-");
                tbl.Add('G', "FGF[Y+>F]+Y");

                for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) str = Rewrite(tbl, str);
            }

            var canvas = new Canvas();

            Content = canvas;

            var sizeGrowth = -1.359672;
            var angleGrowth = -0.138235;

            State state;

            var pen = new Pen(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black), 0.25);

            var geometryGroup = new GeometryGroup();

            Action buildGeometry = () => 
            {
                state = new State()
                {
                    x = 0,
                    y = 0,
                    dir = 0,
                    size = 14.11,
                    angle = -3963.7485
                };

                geometryGroup = new GeometryGroup();

                foreach (var elt in str)
                {
                    if (elt == 'F')
                    {
                        var new_x = state.x + state.size * Math.Cos(state.dir * Math.PI / 180.0);
                        var new_y = state.y + state.size * Math.Sin(state.dir * Math.PI / 180.0);

                        geometryGroup.Children.Add(
                            new LineGeometry(
                                new Point(state.x, state.y),
                                new Point(new_x, new_y)));

                        state.x = new_x;
                        state.y = new_y;
                    }
                    else if (elt == '+') state.dir += state.angle;

                    else if (elt == '-') state.dir -= state.angle;

                    else if (elt == '>') state.size *= (1.0 - sizeGrowth);

                    else if (elt == '<') state.size *= (1.0 + sizeGrowth);

                    else if (elt == ')') state.angle *= (1 + angleGrowth);

                    else if (elt == '(') state.angle *= (1 - angleGrowth);

                    else if (elt == '[') states.Push(state.Clone());

                    else if (elt == ']') state = states.Pop();

                    else if (elt == '!') state.angle *= -1.0;

                    else if (elt == '|') state.dir += 180.0;
                }
            };

            Action populateCanvas = () =>
            {
                var drawingVisualElement = new DrawingVisualElement();

                Console.WriteLine(".");

                canvas.Children.Clear();

                canvas.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform(400.0, 400.0);

                using (var dc = drawingVisualElement.visual.RenderOpen())
                    dc.DrawGeometry(null, pen, geometryGroup);

                canvas.Children.Add(drawingVisualElement);
            };

            MouseDown += (s, e) =>
                {
                    angleGrowth += 0.001;
                    Console.WriteLine("angleGrowth: {0}", angleGrowth);

                    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

                    buildGeometry();
                    populateCanvas();

                    sw.Stop();

                    Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);
                };

            buildGeometry();

            populateCanvas();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WPF's geometry rendering [is just slow](http://jeremiahmorrill.wordpress.com/2011/02/14/a-critical-deep-dive-into-the-wpf-rendering-system/). If you want fast, render using another technology, and host the result in WPF. For example, you could render using Direct3D and host your render target inside a [D3DImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.d3dimage.aspx). [Here's an example using Direct2D instead](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/113991/Using-Direct-D-with-WPF). Or you could draw by manually setting byte values in a RGB buffer and copy that inside a [WriteableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx).

EDIT: as the OP found out, there's also a free library to help out with drawing inside a WriteableBitmap called [WriteableBitmapEx](https://github.com/teichgraf/WriteableBitmapEx/).

Comment: Asik! Thanks for the tip! I've posted an answer including a version of the code which uses `WritableBitmap`. It's very very fast now... :-)

Comment: Taking your other suggestion, I've also made a DirectX version using SlimDX: https://github.com/dharmatech/LSysSlimDx

Answer (score 2):

Below is a version that uses `WritableBitmap` as [Asik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/154766/asik) suggested. I used the [WriteableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) extension methods library for the `DrawLine` method.

It is ridiculously fast now. Thanks Asik!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WpfLsysRender
{
    class DrawingVisualElement : FrameworkElement
    {
        public DrawingVisual visual;

        public DrawingVisualElement() { visual = new DrawingVisual(); }

        protected override int VisualChildrenCount { get { return 1; } }

        protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index) { return visual; }
    }

    class State
    {
        public double size;

        public double angle;

        public double x;

        public double y;

        public double dir;

        public State Clone() { return (State) this.MemberwiseClone(); }
    }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        static string Rewrite(Dictionary<char, string> tbl, string str)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (var elt in str)
            {
                if (tbl.ContainsKey(elt))
                    sb.Append(tbl[elt]);
                else
                    sb.Append(elt);
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Width = 800;
            Height = 800;

            var bitmap = BitmapFactory.New(800, 800);

            Content = new Image() { Source = bitmap };

            var states = new Stack<State>();

            var str = "L";

            {
                var tbl = new Dictionary<char, string>();

                tbl.Add('L', "|-S!L!Y");
                tbl.Add('S', "[F[FF-YS]F)G]+");
                tbl.Add('Y', "--[F-)<F-FG]-");
                tbl.Add('G', "FGF[Y+>F]+Y");

                for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) str = Rewrite(tbl, str);
            }

            var sizeGrowth = -1.359672;
            var angleGrowth = -0.138235;

            State state;

            var lines = new List<Point>();

            var pen = new Pen(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black), 0.25);

            var geometryGroup = new GeometryGroup();

            Action buildLines = () =>
                {
                    lines.Clear();

                    state = new State()
                    {
                        x = 400,
                        y = 400,
                        dir = 0,
                        size = 14.11,
                        angle = -3963.7485
                    };

                    foreach (var elt in str)
                    {
                        if (elt == 'F')
                        {
                            var new_x = state.x + state.size * Math.Cos(state.dir * Math.PI / 180.0);
                            var new_y = state.y + state.size * Math.Sin(state.dir * Math.PI / 180.0);

                            lines.Add(new Point(state.x, state.y));
                            lines.Add(new Point(new_x, new_y));

                            state.x = new_x;
                            state.y = new_y;
                        }
                        else if (elt == '+') state.dir += state.angle;

                        else if (elt == '-') state.dir -= state.angle;

                        else if (elt == '>') state.size *= (1.0 - sizeGrowth);

                        else if (elt == '<') state.size *= (1.0 + sizeGrowth);

                        else if (elt == ')') state.angle *= (1 + angleGrowth);

                        else if (elt == '(') state.angle *= (1 - angleGrowth);

                        else if (elt == '[') states.Push(state.Clone());

                        else if (elt == ']') state = states.Pop();

                        else if (elt == '!') state.angle *= -1.0;

                        else if (elt == '|') state.dir += 180.0;
                    }
                };

            Action updateBitmap = () =>
                {
                    using (bitmap.GetBitmapContext())
                    {
                        bitmap.Clear();

                        for (var i = 0; i < lines.Count; i += 2)
                        {
                            var a = lines[i];
                            var b = lines[i+1];

                            bitmap.DrawLine(
                                (int) a.X, (int) a.Y, (int) b.X, (int) b.Y, 
                                Colors.Black);
                        }
                    }
                };

            MouseDown += (s, e) =>
                {
                    angleGrowth += 0.001;
                    Console.WriteLine("angleGrowth: {0}", angleGrowth);

                    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

                    buildLines();
                    updateBitmap();

                    sw.Stop();

                    Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);
                };

            buildLines();

            updateBitmap();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sweet, I didn't know about this library. Glad to see you could sort it out!

Comment: @Asik one downside is that `DrawLine` doesn't have a *thickness* parameter like many WPF methods do. The lines in the bitmap version are not as fine as those in the WPF version.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested the `WriteableBitmapEx` version, so I don't know how this compares, but I was able to substantially speed up the WPF native version by using `StreamGeometry` and `Freeze()`, which is a way to optimize when there is no animation.  (Though it still doesn't feel as fast as the javascript version)

- The posted version timing is ~0.15s
- The StreamGeometry version timing is ~0.029s

I don't think the timer includes the actual rendering time, just the time to populate the rendering commands. However, it also feels much more speedy. This [WPF performance test](http://kynosarges.org/WpfPerformance.html#comment-3347850974) demonstrates a way to get actual rendering times.

I also removed the `Canvas` and `FrameworkElement`, but it was switching to StreamGeometry that did the speedup.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Diagnostics;

using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

// https://stackoverflow.com/q/22599806/519568

namespace WpfLsysRender
{

    class UpdatableUIElement : UIElement {        
        DrawingGroup backingStore = new DrawingGroup();
        public UpdatableUIElement() {

        }

        protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext) {
            base.OnRender(drawingContext);                    
            drawingContext.DrawDrawing(backingStore);            
        }
        public void Redraw(Action<DrawingContext> fn) {
            var vis = backingStore.Open();            
            fn(vis);
            vis.Close();
        }
    }    

    class State
    {
        public double size;

        public double angle;

        public double x;

        public double y;

        public double dir;

        public State Clone() { return (State)this.MemberwiseClone(); }
    }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        static string Rewrite(Dictionary<char, string> tbl, string str) {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (var elt in str) {
                if (tbl.ContainsKey(elt))
                    sb.Append(tbl[elt]);
                else
                    sb.Append(elt);
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }

        public MainWindow() {
            // InitializeComponent();

            Width = 800;
            Height = 800;

            var states = new Stack<State>();

            var str = "L";

            {
                var tbl = new Dictionary<char, string>();

                tbl.Add('L', "|-S!L!Y");
                tbl.Add('S', "[F[FF-YS]F)G]+");
                tbl.Add('Y', "--[F-)<F-FG]-");
                tbl.Add('G', "FGF[Y+>F]+Y");

                for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) str = Rewrite(tbl, str);
            }

            var lsystem_view = new UpdatableUIElement();
            Content = lsystem_view;


            var sizeGrowth = -1.359672;
            var angleGrowth = -0.138235;

            State state;

            var pen = new Pen(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black), 0.25);

            var geometry = new StreamGeometry();

            Action buildGeometry = () => {
                state = new State() {
                    x = 0,
                    y = 0,
                    dir = 0,
                    size = 14.11,
                    angle = -3963.7485
                };

                geometry = new StreamGeometry();
                var gc = geometry.Open();

                foreach (var elt in str) {
                    if (elt == 'F') {
                        var new_x = state.x + state.size * Math.Cos(state.dir * Math.PI / 180.0);
                        var new_y = state.y + state.size * Math.Sin(state.dir * Math.PI / 180.0);
                        var p1 = new Point(state.x, state.y);
                        var p2 = new Point(new_x, new_y); 
                        gc.BeginFigure(p1,false,false);
                        gc.LineTo(p2,true,true);


                        state.x = new_x;
                        state.y = new_y;
                    }
                    else if (elt == '+') state.dir += state.angle;

                    else if (elt == '-') state.dir -= state.angle;

                    else if (elt == '>') state.size *= (1.0 - sizeGrowth);

                    else if (elt == '<') state.size *= (1.0 + sizeGrowth);

                    else if (elt == ')') state.angle *= (1 + angleGrowth);

                    else if (elt == '(') state.angle *= (1 - angleGrowth);

                    else if (elt == '[') states.Push(state.Clone());

                    else if (elt == ']') state = states.Pop();

                    else if (elt == '!') state.angle *= -1.0;

                    else if (elt == '|') state.dir += 180.0;
                }
                gc.Close();
                geometry.Freeze();
            };

            Action populateCanvas = () => {
                Console.WriteLine(".");

                lsystem_view.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform(400,400);

                lsystem_view.Redraw((dc) => {
                    dc.DrawGeometry(null, pen, geometry);
                });
            };

            MouseDown += (s, e) => {
                angleGrowth += 0.001;
                Console.WriteLine("angleGrowth: {0}", angleGrowth);

                var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

                buildGeometry();
                populateCanvas();

                sw.Stop();

                Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);
            };

            buildGeometry();

            populateCanvas();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a DirectX version](https://github.com/dharmatech/LSysSlimDx) using SlimDX.