# Fastest way to draw high amount of 2D shapes in WPF/C#

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, drawing

I need to draw a high amount of 2D shapes (Rectangles, Triangles and lines in a WPF-Application. The picture shows roughly what i intend to do. There can be more than 200 000 graphical objects in such a szenario. In the worst case, when the user is completly scrolled out, i have to draw all those graphical objects.

Important for me is, that i can remove individual objects for example a specific line without having to redraw everything. Currently I´m using DrawingVisuals.

Is there a solution to do this in a faster way?

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IitZM.png)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713864/high-performance-graphics-using-the-wpf-visual-layer

Comment: The marked duplicate provides two _possible_ approaches. Note though that WPF does its own caching of rendered output, so the suggested solutions may or may not address your problem. Unfortunately, the alternative is to interpret your question broadly, in which case the question itself is simply too broad to be answered. In that case, please post a new question, making sure you provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces your performance problem, and also provide a clear, precise description of your performance goal and an explanation of why that goal is reasonably achievable.